# What is the meaning of と in 足りないからとキスして?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-と

This is part of a song called マリーゴールド.

> アイラブユーの言葉じゃ
> 足りないからとキスして
> 雲がまだ二人の影を残すから
> いつまでもいつまでもこのまま

I'm quite confused to understand what と is doing in 足りない**からと**キスして.

Maybe it's just an emphasis and the meaning is similar with 足りない**から**キスして.

Or maybe it means 「...足りない**から**」**と**（言いながら）キスして.

What is the meaning of と in this case?